# Google Glass - Take a picture and save it programmatically

Tags: android, google-glass, android-camera-intent

I want to start the camera intent within my app to take a picture and save it to internal storage. I'm using the code of google developers page [Capturing images or video](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/camera#capturing_images_or_video).
In the processPictureWhenReady method I've implemented the following code to save the picture:

```
private void processPictureWhenReady(final String picturePath) {
    Log.v("path processPictureWhenReady ", " " + picturePath);
    final File pictureFile = new File(picturePath);

    if (pictureFile.exists()) {
        // The picture is ready; process it.
        try {

            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            int w = imageBitmap.getWidth();
            int h = imageBitmap.getHeight();

            Bitmap bm2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, w / 2,
                    h / 2, true);

            imageBitmap = bm2.copy(bm2.getConfig(), true);

            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    imageBitmap, "test", "Test");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exc", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

The camera intent is starting and then I have "tap to accept" to take a picture. But then nothing happens. I have a log message in my onActivityResult method and noticed that the method is not beeing called.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. I have the same problem. I'm following the case [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=555) in the meantime

I've seen people try implementing the preview mode with SurfaceView (I haven't personally gotten it to work but it's worth a shot).  Also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514903/gdk-picture-intent-gets-stuck-on-tap-to-accept?lq=1) for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method it worked for me very well.

```
private void processPictureWhenReady(final String picturePath) {
    final File pictureFile = new File(picturePath);
    if(pictureFile.exists()){


    }


    if (pictureFile.exists()) {

    } else {

        final File parentDirectory = pictureFile.getParentFile();
        FileObserver observer = new FileObserver(parentDirectory.getPath()) {
            private boolean isFileWritten;

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
                if (!isFileWritten) {
                    // For safety, make sure that the file that was created in
                    // the directory is actually the one that we're expecting.
                    File affectedFile = new File(parentDirectory, path);
                    isFileWritten = (event == FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE && affectedFile.equals(pictureFile));

                   if (isFileWritten) {
                        stopWatching();

                        // Now that the file is ready, recursively call
                        // processPictureWhenReady again (on the UI thread).
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                processPictureWhenReady(picturePath);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        observer.startWatching();
    }
}
```